# Is there a codecvt decoding scenario where the destination buffer needs space for more than one internal character?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, codecvt

When using `std::codecvt`'s `in` method to decode an external byte sequence to an internal char sequence, is there a situation where the destination buffer of internal chars needs space for more than one internal char?

Here is some code for reference:

```
// const std::locale& loc;
// mbstate_t state;
// const char *extern_buf_ptr;
// const char *extern_buf_eptr;
const std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t> *pcodecvt = &std::use_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t> >(loc);

wchar_t intern_char;
wchar_t *tmp;
std::codecvt_base::result in_res = pcodecvt->in(state,
        extern_buf_ptr, extern_buf_eptr, extern_buf_ptr,
        &intern_char, &intern_char + 1, tmp);
```

This is a simplification of some template code that I have written to decode bytes read individually from a Winsock `SOCKET`, where the user desires "unbuffered" input. Basically, with each iteration of a loop, a byte is read into the external buffer. The loop terminates when `in_res` is not `std::codecvt_base::partial`.

What I am wondering is: Is there a scenario where a call to `in()` would require space in the destination buffer for more than one internal character? I.e., is there a scenario that would make the above-described loop an infinite loop?

Comment: Note that `wchar_t` is defined to be wide enough to hold any character value of "the system's character set". So it is reasonable to assume that any `wchar_t` string sequence is required to be processable one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a note in `§22.4.1.4.2/3` to that extent:

> `basic_filebuf` assumes that the mappings from internal to external characters is `1` to `N`: a `codecvt` facet that is used by `basic_filebuf` must be able to translate characters one internal character at a time

Sounds like any locale that's good for IO streams is good for your use as well.